# I still have the blurry text issue when using higher DPI on laptop with an external display

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1709

I just upgraded my windows 10 enterprise to version 1709 build 16299.19 on laptop and tested the 125% scaling with external monitor at 100% scaling. Disappointingly, the blurry text issue is still there...especially for Office apps (Office pro plus 2016 MSO 16.0.4549.1000 64BIT). I tested with laptop screen as main display and also tested with external monitor as main display, made no difference than before the update...

My understanding is: with fall creators update, I just need to re-open the app to fix the blurry text issue. It is the only reason I installed the update... But am I wrong?

Comment: link to your referred 'blurry text issue' ?

Comment: This is going to be a per-application problem, since not all applications are even dpi aware. The blurriness probably is simply a non-aware program being scaled after rendering. Blurring is an expected outcome of bitmap scaling. Even MS products suffer from DPI scaling issues ( https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/04/04/high-dpi-scaling-improvements-desktop-applications-windows-10-creators-update/ ), but "yeah" a screenshot or phone camera shot might help.

Comment: @Yorik, do the fix is to upgrade office apps in my case?

Comment: @m1xed0s I posted nearly same [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1263563/) and linked to MS blog that advertised supposed DPI improvements. Nobody has a clue or seem to care.

Comment: You can vote for this bug in Feedback tool: https://aka.ms/Xf2mgs