# Apps still blurry after DPI change on Fall Creators Update

Tags: windows-10, resolution, high-dpi, windows-10-v1709

So I've updated my Surface Pro 4 to Fall Creators and the much touted [fix for high DPI screen](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2017/07/07/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-16237-pc) doesn't seem to be there.

When I change screen from high dpi to low dpi or back, there is still a red warning in display settings that you need to sign out to fix some applications. When I restart legacy apps they come back as blurry as ever. There's no improvement. If anything the scaling seems even worse than it was (more blurry).

Is anyone else seeing this too?

Comment: Vote for it in Feedback tool here: https://aka.ms/Xf2mgs

Comment: Yes, Win10 FCU handles DPI in yet another problematic way :)

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 being one of those apps...

Answer (score -2):

Try these methods:

Solution 1: Before you begin, get the latest updates
Solution 2: Run the Program Compatibility Troubleshooter
Solution 3: Change your main display if you have more than one display
Solution 4: Check with the app's publisher

Here is the detailed guide how to operate them:

How do I fix desktop app display issues?

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4036278/surface-how-do-i-fix-desktop-app-display-issues

Comment: Irrelevant answer.